# VBA: Restrict function arguments to only selected values?

Tags: vba, excel, parameters, enums

Is it possible to define a VBA function so it will only accept specific predefined values as parameter values?  As example, if I create a function like this:

```
Function Test(vTxt as Boolean)
    Msgbox vText
End Function
```

and call it from any other Sub I have to give True or False for `vTxt`, and it won't accept any other values.  For example, I can call `Test` as:

```
Sub Example ()
    Call Test(True)
End Sub
```

Like that, can I set up other parameters in the function so that the caller must choose from only predetermined options?  For example:

```
Function Test2(vTxt as <something>)
    Msgbox vText
End Function
```

and when calling `Test2`, the caller must specify Option 1, Option 2 or Option 3 for variable `vTxt`.  I don't want to create multiple optional arguments, but just one argument with multiple predetermined values.  What can I use for `<something>`?

Comment: How many different options do you need? You might look into using a `Select Case` method

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, what do you mean by: "And call it from any other Sub I have the option to give True or False for vTxt and it won't accept any other values. Like" because you give an example of calling it with a Boolean value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to give the user a limited number of choices for an argument.  [Enum types](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx) are a way to do that.  At the beginning of a module, create your type:

```
Public Enum TestChoices
    Option1
    Option2
    Option3
End Enum
```

Then, in your function, take a `TestChoices` parameter:

```
Sub Test(vMsg as TestChoices)
    Dim message as String
    Select Case vMsg
        Case Option1: message="option 1 selected"
        Case Option2: message="option 2 selected"
        Case Option3: message="option 3 selected"
    End Select
    MsgBox message
End Sub
```

See also the [MSDN docs for enums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251516.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much cxw. That's exactly what I wanted.... Saved my day.

Comment: @AnuragPattanayak glad to help!  PS - don't forget to check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com) for a more detailed introduction to the site.  Good luck with your program!

Comment: @cwx sure I will... no doubt